# Java text based adventure game, what to put under my main method

Tags: java

I'm making a text based adventure game with java, im a first year computer science student.

I made a  room, exit, creature, item and world class and put in the API that was given to me in the class. It was just basic methods and some constructors.

We're suppose to create a textAdventure class were we bring together all the other classes and create the game.

The player and game class was given to me and my professor did all the necessary code in order to make the game run in that class.

My problem is I don't know how to start in my `TextAdventure` Class, also thats where my main method is.

So I'm confused on how to make a starting room and how to put an exit in that room leading to another room.

Here's some code

```
public class MyTextAdventure {

    private Room room1;    
    private Room room2;    
    private Room room3;    
    private Room room4;   
    private Room room5; 
    private Room room6;
    private Room room7; 
    private Room room9;
    private Room room10;




public static void main(String [] args){

}
```

If I wanted to make a player start in `room1`, can I just do this.

```
public static void main(String [] args){


public Room startingRoom;

}
```

I have already declared `startingRoom` in the room class.

I'm sorry if my skills are bad, I just have no idea what I'm doing and where to start.

Comment: `main` should do the setup and loading, then off load the rest of the functionality to the core program.

Comment: so for the main do i just include the methods i created in the other classes?

Comment: I don't know, all I have is a small, out of context, code snippet.  I would suggest that the actual work of making your program work is the responsibility of another class and `main` could be used to initialise this class to it's required starting starting state, for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array to keep track of your rooms. This allows you to avoid having to keep track of 10 different variable names. It also allows you to do math on the array index. For example, if you wanted to set the current room from 3 to 4, you wouldn't have to check which room was set to current. You could just do `currentRoom++`

Try something like this.

```
public class MyTextAdventure {

    private Room[] rooms; //array for all rooms
    int currentRoom = 0;
    boolean over;

    //class constructor
    public MyTextAdventure() {
        rooms = new Room[10]; //Initialize new room array of size 10
        over = false; //game is not over yet

        for(int i = 0; i < rooms.length; i++) {
            //Initialize all rooms
            rooms[i] = new Room();
        }
    }

    public void start() {
        //do your game loop in here
        while(!over) {

        }   
    }

}

public static void main(String [] args){
    MyTextAdventure adventure = new MyTextAdventure();
    adventure.start();
}
```

The main function should just start your game. Functions and classes should be designed to accomplish a singular task that is clear. Name classes, functions and variables so that you know exactly what they are doing.

Using the current room as an integer allows you to make use of it as an array index. For example if you want to get the current room you can do this for a function.

```
public Room getCurrentRoom() {
    return rooms[currentRoom];
}
```